# tinyMCE modal box dialog

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I want to make a button and when it's clicked then modal box opens where user have to enter url, click insert and then url is inserted to editor. So far I have added button and opened modal box but how could I get back those values? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using window.showModalDialog to open your modal dialog box, then according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536759%28VS.85%29.aspx), it sounds like you can return a value from the modal dialog by setting the [returnValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534371%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) property on window. It sounds like it will work in Firefox as well, based on the [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.showModalDialog) documentation. In the dialog window, you would set the returnValue property:

```
window.returnValue = GetTheUrlThatWasTypedIn();
```

And then in the parent window, retrieve it into a variable when you open the modal dialog:

```
var theUrl = window.showModalDialog(/* parameters go here */);
```